# How to speed up MYSQL query with Multiple Join tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im having trouble with my queries, they are taken ages to product results. I only have 13,000 records in the main table, and then link up to a few other tables which are mainly attribute tables with a dozen or so records inside them

I have used indexing before but only when using queries on one table and not joining else where.

here is my query

```
SELECT
    product_data.id                         AS id,
    product_data.sku                        AS sku,
    product_data.barcode                    AS barcode,
    product_data.title                      AS title,
    product_data.attrib_releasedate         AS attrib_releasedate,
    product_category_main.id                AS category_main_id,
    product_category_main.name              AS category_main_description,
    product_category_sub.id                 AS category_sub_id,
    product_category_sub.name               AS category_sub_description,
    product_category_sub.description_short  AS category_sub_description_short,
    product_condition.id                    AS condition_id,
    product_condition.name                  AS condition_description,       
    attrib_pegi.name                        AS attrib_pegi,
    attrib_region.name                      AS attrib_region,
    product_data.asin                       AS asin,
    product_data.cex                        AS cex

FROM product_data
    INNER JOIN product_category_main 
        ON product_data.category_main_id = product_category_main.id

    INNER JOIN product_category_sub 
        ON product_data.category_sub_id = product_category_sub.id

    LEFT JOIN product_condition 
        ON product_data.condition_id = product_condition.id

    LEFT JOIN attrib_pegi
        ON attrib_pegi.id = product_data.attrib_pegi

    LEFT JOIN attrib_region
        ON attrib_region.id = product_data.attrib_region

WHERE
    title<>'' AND product_category_main.id = 1

ORDER BY
    category_main_id, title
```

Comment: Put indexes on every join if you don't have that already.

Comment: Can you provide the EXPLAIN for the above. Proper DDLs would help too.

Comment: I made all the other table fields i was calling, indexed too, but was still having the same problem it seems it was the amount of HMTL code i was generating from the results and loops to make the code as dynamic as possible that was causing the big delay.